Setting up Stripe Checkout
I'm trying to setup a process payment that uses Stripe Checkout. However, I'm not sure how to get these fields under Process Live Payments. 

There's more info on how to access these keys and how they work here and a longer explaination here.
Note that:

For security, in live mode Stripe only shows you a secret or restricted API key one time. Store the key in a safe place where you won’t lose it. To help yourself remember where you stored it, you can leave a note on the key in the Dashboard. If you lose the key, you can roll it or delete it and create another.

From the longer explanation:


In the Developers Dashboard, select the API keys tab (link takes you to live keys).
In the Standard keys list or Restricted keys list, in the row for the key
you want to reveal, click Reveal live key.
Copy the key value by clicking it.
Save the key value.
Save the key value.
Click Hide test key.
Click the overflow menu () next to the key, then select Edit key…
In the Note field, enter the location where you saved the key, then click Save.


If you're logged into Stripe and have permssions to access the Developer Dashboard, your test mode keys should appear in a table part way down this help page too.

It's the same api keys that you'd use for regular stripe, or you could make additional api keys if you want them separate.
Or are you asking about how to make developer stripe account live?

I want to setup a live service process payment but I'm not sure how to go about it. I seen that I need a PHP file with the API key but not sure where to put the file.

No you need to go into your stripe account and generate api keys. Then put those keys into the civi form you've shown in your question.

There's a toggle at stripe to switch to live mode if your account isn't live yet.

Okay well I did that and entered a dummy card and accepted my card but the transaction didn't go through. The test member I added still had a status of pending with incomplete transaction.
